# Different results between function Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal and Fitness.HistoryApi.readData

Tags: java, android

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi.html#readData%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataReadRequest%29) documentation

Functions: `Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal` and

```
readData(client, new DataReadRequest.Builder()
   .setTimeRange(midnight.getMillis(), now.getMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
   .aggregate(DataTypes.STEP_COUNT_DELTA, AggregateDataTypes.STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
   .build());
```

**must be equivalent**, but I received 1663 steps (equal to `Google Fit` App) from readDailyTotal and 152 steps from readData for the same time period. Why?
We can't use only readDailyTotal, because this function returns data only for current day.